# UTC vs EST timezone (UI vs Backend)

Tags: java, angular

I have an application where all backend components follow EST(America/New york)
For a specific flow we need to capture and pass the creation date and time from UI to backend.
Would there be any pre-defined standard where UI should only pass the date in UTC?
Can't UI too follow and pass the date and time in EST(America/New york) equivalent of it.

Eg UI sending the creation date like - "2022-11-04T15:07:18.799Z"
But in EST time zone the time was "11:04.19" AM

Please note

1. That our user base is all across USA, so it might fall into different time zone, but in case of backend it only follows (America/New york)
2. The backend and UI has to always display/process these times in EST time zone, so regardless of the users location in US we always display date and time to the user in EST(America/New york). So now when there is a need now for UI to pass the creation time, why can't UI pass it in (America/New york)?

Comment: There is indeed a standard:  ISO 8601.  Which is what `2022-11-04T15:07:18.799Z` is.  No matter what the UI looks like to the end user, it should always pass date-time information to its business layer in ISO 8601 format, so there is no ambiguity about the data’s meaning.

Comment: Specifically the `Z` in that format indicates UTC. Technically your application can easily default to one specific timezone for all its backend and API needs. But picking America/New York has the major drawback that it's a timezone that switches between summer time and winter time, and manual interpretation of logs and such becomes messy (assuming its handled correctly everywhere). UTC has the big advantage that it's consistent and doesn't switch over.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

I recommend that you not fixate on the New York time. Keep your data in UTC (`Instant`).

```
Instant.parse ( "2022-11-04T15:07:18.799Z" )
```

Apply a **time zone only for presentation** and where required for specific business logic (`ZonedDateTime`).

```
instant.atZone( zoneId )
```

## Details

> should only pass the date in UTC

Use the `java.time.Instant` class to represent a moment in UTC. That is, a moment with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Always in UTC.
```

The `Z` on the end of your example text means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Comes from aviation and military conventions, standardized in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse ( "2022-11-04T15:07:18.799Z" ) ;
```

You’ll find that date-time handling is easier if you use only UTC for logging, debugging, data storage, data exchange, and most business logic.

> the date and time in EST(America/New york) equivalent

Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generally best to use the zoned time only for presentation to users, and for particular points of business logic.

Beware: “EST” is not a [real time zone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). `America/New_York` is.

Generate text using the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.